# Remove everything before string in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to remove everything before a string 'EXEC'. How to do that in Notepad++?

There are many examples with regular expressions and special characters but my sentence has two EXEC so none of them solved my problem. I want to ignore EXECUTION and remove everything before EXEC.

Example:

```
Abcdefghijklmn EXECUTION EXEC myfilename here
```

Expected Result:

```
EXEC myfilename here
```

Comment: you can't rely on finding exactly your issue searching the internet. But you can rely on finding the pieces you need to put yourself a solution together. Really you can't just ask for every query you want. You need to be able to construct your own from pieces found on the internet. It is full of regex examples and cheat-sheets. I apologize if I seem too harsh. My intention is to help you. You need to develop the skill to combine fragments found on various sources into a solution for your specific problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
^.*(?=EXEC\s)
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6mBhLX/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of the String
- `.*` - 0+ occurrences of any character which is not a newline character
- `(?=EXEC\s)` - [Positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which returns the position which is immediately followed by `EXEC`(with a space)

**OUTPUT:**

Before replacing:

[image]

After replacing:

[image]

Comment: Space should be present before EXEC else it wont work

Answer (score 9):

You can replace the following regexp:

```
.*EXEC
```

with:

```
EXEC
```

Comment: And don't forget to check the ". matches newline" option

Comment: @RaphaelMüllner you mean "uncheck" :p

Comment: @Zumo de Vidrio . As i mentioned it has two words EXEC and EXECUTIONSTACK. I need to remove everything before EXEC. How to ignore the string  EXECUTIONSTACK?

Comment: @Ask_SO: Add a space after EXEC